# Is this code encrypted in some way?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I this is a tiny bit of the code for a function that I saw on a website using inspect element and then using the console to find the definition of the function. If this is encrypted has anyone got any idea on how to decrypt it, and if so what type of encryption is this. The actual function is around 200 lines of this code and I have no idea how to go about even trying to decrypt it.

```
var_0x4d51['VWxiWnA=','YWQ+','ZGxPSVU=','a3
```

Comment: It certainly looks a bit obfuscated. The sample is too small. I guess the answer is no.

Comment: The function is around 100 lines of this pattern of code, I have never seen it before though.

Comment: I believe so @Cowthulhu

Comment: It looks to be encrypted (or hashed, or something of that nature) in some way - but I could be wrong. If it's javascript, and the decryption (or equivalent) is also in javascript, then you should be able to reverse engineer it as everything will be done clientside. I would look into reverse engineering javascript.

Comment: It looks like the sample you're giving us is cut off. But syntactically it looks like JavaScript. It just looks like it is obfuscated...which is a common technique to make plaintext scripting languages more difficult to reverse engineer by replacing any sensible variable names, function names, values, and so on with complete gibberish.

De-obfuscation involves figuring out what each gibberish symbol/token refers to, and then doing a find-and-replace on the whole script and replacing it with something more meaningful to you.

Comment: It looks "encrypted". But in the end it is just JavaScript with a bunch of variables with weird names. It would take a long time to name things and make it understandable, but that's not impossible...

Comment: @Cowthulhu (and @BrunoLM) although what your saying is a feasible (albeit relatively pointless) technique, this really doesn't look like actual encryption given that it still seems to be syntactically equivalent to JavaScript (and a whole lot of other languages). This is called obfuscation.

Comment: **Please** stop using the word "encrypted".  This isn't encryption and has nothing to do with encryption.  The code is **obfuscated**, not hashed or encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give a proper answer to this question, this looks like [**obfuscation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) rather than full-fledged **encryption**. The reason being that, although many of the symbols/tokens in this line look like gibberish, it is still syntactically okay JavaScript.

Such technique involves changing the names of otherwise self-describing variable names, function names, enumerations, and so on with complete gibberish. It is very common when trying to protect software that will be distributed in plaintext to a customer (e.g. software that is written in scripting languages like Lua, JavaScript, Python, etc. and is not being distributed in a compiled form). It simply makes it more difficult for a human to reverse engineer the software because it removes any characteristics of self-documentation and readability from the code. If you can, however, deduce what a particular name is supposed to represent, a simple find-and-replace on the code will allow you to transform it back into a more descriptive and readable phrase.

I can see obfuscation being used to hide the intention of code from filters that claim to be anti-virus, anti-spam, anti-ad, and so on. Especially self-obfuscating code. In fact, this is the reason why some malware is very difficult to detect, and why lots of ads nowadays make it past browser ad-blockers. Such annoyances dynamically obfuscate their detectable traits so as to make it extremely difficult for filters to detect them using known patterns.

In this case, as others have said, the names may have been obfuscated using a hashing algorithm such as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). If you are interested, search around for obfuscators and de-obfuscators on the web...or do the tasks manually using your text editor's find-and-replace mechanism.

As a slight side-note, compiled languages are, to a certain extent, self-obfuscating in the sense that byte code and machine code are not self-documenting nor easily readable by humans. They can technically be "de-obfuscated", to a certain extent, using similar find-and-replace techniques if one knows what they are looking for, what machine the code was compiled for, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be base64-encoded, because of the trailing "="(s)
[Base64](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) adds equal signs as padding.

The entire line is similar to the lines found in spam-infected web pages, so it might be the case.

Maybe you can [check out another encoded strings](https://www.base64decode.org) if you have them and glue the parts to get the whole message.